# Did you hear about alphametics?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, alphabet

### Task

The letters spell out actual words, but if you replace each letter with a digit from 0–9, it also “spells” an arithmetic equation. The trick is to figure out which letter maps to each digit. All the occurrences of each letter must map to the same digit, no digit can be repeated, and no “word” can start with the digit 0.

## Input

```
HAWAII + IDAHO + IOWA + OHIO = STATES
```

## Output

```
510199 + 98153 + 9301 + 3593 = 621246
```

## Input

```
I + LOVE + YOU = DORA
```

## Output

```
1 + 2784 + 975 = 3760
```

## Input

```
SEND + MORE = MONEY
```

## Output

```
9567 + 1085 = 10652
```

## Rules

- Standard [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- shortest code wins.
- addition only

## Appendix

for other Inputs you gotta keep in mind you can only have 10 different characters(to assign values 0-9)

Comment: "No digit can be repeated" means that no two letters can map to the same digit? Also are we guaranteed that the input has a solution? Are we guaranteed that it has a unique solution?

Comment: @LuisMendo "addition only" for your second question, but I assume that the `=` in the first example is a typo.

Comment: It can have multiple solutions, BUT the equation must be valid like ‚mama‘ is invalid due to repetition

Comment: Yeah == was typo edited

Comment: May we take input as `STATES = HAWAII + IDAHO + IOWA + OHIO`? May we require input to not have spaces?

Comment: @Adám you can but don’t have to handle spaces, your input is also fine

Comment: I don't understand what's invalid about `MAMA` (which isn't even an equation to begin with).

Comment: @Arnauld *no “word” can start with the digit 0*

Comment: Also this had no winning criterion. I added [tag:code-golf].

Comment: What inputs are acceptable? Can we take the input as e.g. `[[[S,E,N,D],[M,O,R,E]],[M,O,N,E,Y]]`?

Comment: Also can we assume that such a mapping is possible?

Comment: Will there only be upper case letters `A-Z`? Can we choose lower case if we want?

Comment: The mapping (if <=10 Chars) always has a solution, you can take the input as list.

Comment: Upper/lower are allowed. But it‘s either only upper or lower then.

Comment: WHO voted duplicate? It’s obviously not?!

Comment: @0x45 Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/a-subset-of-verbal-arithmetic) in my opinion. We've had this kind of mapping challenges before. Anyway, if other users disagree they can vote to reopen it. But IMO it is way too closely related to be kept open.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I don‘t see similarities, but let the community decide

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 104 bytes

```js
f=(s,o,c=s.match(/[A-Z]/))=>c?[...2**29+'4'].some(i=>o&1<<i?0:f(r=s.split(c).join(i),o|1<<i))&&r:eval(s)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(s,o,c=s.match(/[A-Z]/))=>c?[...2**29+'4'].some(i=>o&1<<i?0:f(r=s.split(c).join(i),o|1<<i))&&r:eval(s)

console.log(f('I + LOVE + YOU == DORA'))
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = (                               // f = recursive function taking:
  s,                                //   s = input string
  o,                                //   o = bitmask of used digits
  c = s.match(/[A-Z]/)              //   c = next alphabetical character in s
) =>                                //       (either null or a single-element array)
  c ?                               // if c is not null:
    [...2**29 + '4'].some(i =>      //   for each character i of '5368709124'
      o & 1 << i ?                  //     if this digit was already used:
        0                           //       ignore this iteration
      :                             //     else:
        f(                          //       do a recursive call to f() with:
          r = s.split(c).join(i),   //         all characters c replaced with i
          o | 1 << i                //         the updated bitmask
        )                           //       end of recursive call
    ) && r                          //   end of some(): if successful, return r
  :                                 // else:
    eval(s)                         //   evaluate this fully numerical expression
```

Comment: 104, since == is allowed